# How can I insert and get data from a collection of java objects to be able to create a parameterized method?

Tags: java, junit5, junit-jupiter

The form "inputConditionsTest[0]" is incorrect.How can I get the first values of my collection <Object[]>???

public class ControllaCondizioniParamTest {

```
    private  ControllaCondizioni controllaCondizioni;

    public static Collection<Object[]> inputConditionsTest() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { 5, 3, true, true, true },
                { 1, 2, false, true, true },
                { 3, 3, false, false, true },
                { 2, 4, true, false, true}, 
                { 9, 3, false, true, false},
                { 10, 5, true, false, true }
        });
    }
        @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource(value = "inputConditionsTest")
    void testConditionsMethod(Collection<Object[]> inputConditionsTest) {
        controllaCondizioni = new ControllaCondizioni();
        int a = inputConditionsTest[0]
        int b = inputConditionsTest[1];
        boolean c = inputConditionsTest[2];
        boolean d = inputConditionsTest[3];
        boolean expected = inputConditionsTest[4];
        assertEquals(expected, controllaCondizioni.Verifica(a, b, c, expected));
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using JUnit's Parameterized incorrectly. The parameter source method should return a collection of arrays, you do that correctly. But the *test method* should receive the array elements as separate arguments:

```
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource(value = "inputConditionsTest")
    void testConditionsMethod(int a, int b, boolean c, boolean d, boolean expected) {
        controllaCondizioni = new ControllaCondizioni();
        assertEquals(expected, controllaCondizioni.Verifica(a, b, c, expected));
    }
```